# Compile without IBM WAS 7 installed

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, ibm-was

We are using IBM WAS 7 as the server for our application. But the organization's rules do not allow us to have servers installed in workstations. I have this J2EE web project that uses WAS 7 as the target server runtime.

At first, I installed WebSphere® Application Server V7.0 tools for Eclipse. I thought it will provide the runtime along with it as well. Now I can see the option of WAS 7 in server runtime, but on selecting it I have to provide the path where WAS 7 is installed. And I don't have that.

Can I use any other server runtime and expect that it will work within WAS 7? If not, is there any way to just get the runtime without installing the server?

Comment: Does your organization have a test WAS 7 server?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fully standard Java EE APIs (and no special WebSphere classes), you can simply add the Java EE API jars to your project classpath.

Since WebSphere 7 is Java EE 5 compliant, you could go to maven and [download the Java EE 5 API jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javaee/javaee-api/5) and add it to your classpath.  This will allow you to compile your code in eclipse.

If you need some WebSphere specific APIs, then you need to tell your development organization that you need to have access to the Jars somehow so that you can compile your code against them.  Have your legal team investigate if you can distribute the WebSphere jars to developers for compiling purposes.

Another option is [downloading WebSphere Liberty](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-using-non-eclipse-environments/) (which is free for development useage) and using Liberty to compile and run your code locally. Note that you will have to install a really old version of Liberty to have it match up with the Java EE 5 WebSphere version 7 (currently Liberty is EE 7 compliant).

Disclaimer: I am a developer for both WebSphere Traditional and WebSphere Liberty.  The reason I am suggesting Liberty instead of other app servers is because the askers org is ultimately using WebSphere Traditional, and Liberty will have the closest match in behavior.

Answer (score -1):

It depends a little on the meaning "But the organization's rules do not allow us to have servers installed in workstations".

Often this is due to licencing constraints, in which case you can install an open-source J2EE server like Tomcat or JBOSS. So long as your apps do not call IBM-specific libraries, the same binary should run on any of these environments.

Comment: Using WebSphere Application Server for Developers version is free of charge for development, you dont need any license for that and you can download it, no need to use open-source server if your delivery platform is WAS.